# Listing item on Ebay

Tags: c#, mysql, ebay-api

I am making in application in .NET (c# .NET) and its kind of like Turbo Lister but the only difference is that it is connected to MySQL. My program will work like this:

You add a new item it gets stored in Database and with user's permission it will also make an API call to add the new item to eBay.

So I want to know in order to list items on Ebay like Turbo Lister what are the required fields or information's do i need in order to list an item successfully? (Talking about Database Structure)

Comment: ... the same as the API for listing an item, I'd guess?

Comment: Yes, i know but you can't just make an api call without just title and price. You need to have minimum info. you need to feed to ebay in order to make listing.

Comment: Figure out what the required items are by trial and error.  You can also look at the sdk should tell you.

Comment: That is my last option if i don't get any replies.

Comment: [Here's the documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/AddItem.html#Request). It identifies which fields are optional and which are required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The eBay documentation is very clear about which fields are required, which are optional, and which are conditional. Under **Call-Specific Input Fields** on the [AddItem](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/AddItem.html#callInputFields) call reference, the third column ("Occurrence") indicates this for every available field.